# Autofill dynamic text box(s) based on input from other textbox (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have 1 or more text boxes that i need to copy the value to the other text boxes when the first textbox changes. These are dynamically created so it can be any number of textboxes Here is the html markup for the textbox:

```
<input type="text" name="PreviousQuotePrice@(Model.SanQuoteLineKey)" class="PreviousQuotePrice" id="PreviousQuotePrice@(Model.SanQuoteLineKey)" value="@(Model.PreviousQuotePrice)"/>
```

I've got as far as this with my jQuery and the alert shows but I'm stumped as to how I can copy the value from the one textbox to the other.

```
$(".PreviousQuotePrice").live('input', function () {
    alert('Test');
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And, where is the other textbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real thing you will need to know is how you will group those dynamically created textboxes, will they all have the same class? The same name? If your dynamically created textboxes all have the same class it is pretty easy to do.

> ```
> $(document).ready(function() {
>   $(".PreviousQuotePrice").on('keyup',function(){
>     $(".otherClass").val($(".PreviousQuotePrice").val());
>   });
> });
> ```

This example can be seen in action here : http://jsfiddle.net/Hryax/